# Add image to CheckedTextView from SD card or internal storage

Tags: android, checkedtextview

Simple question:

I want to change the **CheckedTextView**'s icon using images from the **SD card** or **internal storage**, but cannot find any method to do this, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You Can convert the target image to drawable and set that drawable as background to the checkedTextView

```
 Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
 mCTxtView.setBackground(drawable);
```

Comment: I mean, add image to **CheckedTextView**, but I cannot find any method to do it.

Comment: You don't want to set the image in drawable folder ?

Comment: Cause I need to download some pictures into the sd card or internal storage, then I want to use them in the CheckedTextView.